# MSMQ in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, msmq

I have a small query whether MSMQ can be supported in eclipse IDE through its java client? because I have not seen any tutorial explaing it. Everywhere I found that run it via Visual Studio.

So was confused before trying it in eclipse.

Please respond.It will be really helpful for me!

Thanks,
Yash